Where can I get the virtual port name for a serial monitor in Simulide
I'm trying to set up a Serial Monitor in SimulIDE, so I can keep track of the variables in my Simulation:

However I apparently need a port to open the monitor:

I've seen Youtube videos where they use portnames like "/tmp/ttyS1" or "/dev/ttys001", but non of them work on my Windows machine. How can I get this to work?

If you are running a simulation, you don't have any physical serial ports to open. Only physical devices you plug into your computer can be opened. If you need help with how to use some PC program, this isn't an electrical engineering issue.

Initial attempt at answer, and probably wrong
When first answered picked on the port names, thinking physical serial ports were in use.
Port names such as /tmp/ttyS1 or /dev/ttys001 are used for serial ports under Linux.
Under Windows serial port names are of form COM<number>. E.g. COM2.
The SuperUser question How to view serial COM ports but not through Device Manager on how to list COM port numbers under Windows, in addition to the Device Manager.
SimulIDE virtual serial ports
On reading the question again, realised that SimulIDE is actually a simulator.
SimulIDE Knowledge Base – SERIAL MONITOR – contains:

Right-Click on the Component and select “Open Serial Monitor”.
If there are more than one UART you will see a list of available Uarts.
Choose one to open the Serial Monitor widget for that Uart

On the above web page, the virtual serial port name is shown as Uart1.
